# Displaying names from a list right after each other in XNA

Tags: c#, list, loops, for-loop, foreach

I'm not too sure on how to explain this but hopefully you get what i mean.

Currently i'm trying to pull out all the usernames from my database and put into a list, and it works, then later i try to pull out all the names I've put into the list to then display it on the screen, however i cannot get this working.

I've tried with a foreach, but this just displays the last name in the list:

```
 foreach (var text in allUsers)
                        {
                            message = text.Bruger.ToString();
                        }
```

Which is not what i wanted, i wanted to display each name after each other, so i tried this instead:

```
foreach (var text in allUsers)
                        {
                            message += text.Bruger.ToString() + '\n';
                        }
```

But this just keeps displaying the same over and over again, theres only 4 names in the list, but it displays each name more then 4 times each (And keeps going).

Then i tried making a bool which is set to false, so that when the "For" loop has run twice it would set the bool to false which would stop the loop. However this does stop the loop, however it stops it after having displayed ALL the names at least 5 times each (The names run out from the screen, so i can only count each name 5 times).

That code looks like this:

```
bool isDoneAdding = false;

                if (isDoneAdding == false)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (var text in allUsers)
                        {
                            message += text.Bruger.ToString() + '\n';
                        }
                        if (i == 2)
                        {
                            isDoneAdding = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The answer to this might be very easy, but i am still a newbie and i cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

This is where i add all the users to the list:

```
        List<User> allUsers = new List<User>();

 MathAndYouDBEntities db = new MathAndYouDBEntities();


            foreach (User user in db.Users)
            {
                allUsers.Add(user);

            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `text' variable you're getting back is an individual user? What does 'Bruger' refer to?

Also, the bottom code segment will produce the same result that the middle one does, but it will do it twice. If you're using a conventional for loop, you probably don't want a foreach inside as well.

Comment: Bruger is the Danish word for "User" Its basicly what the table is called in my database, and yeah I've checked through the debug, it runs through them all and then posts the last one it got. However with the += one then it just keeps adding them all for some reason, not stopping.

Comment: I suspect then that allUsers is not, in fact, the collection of all users in the database... at least, not in a form that the C# foreach loop can iterate through.

Comment: I'll add the bit where "allUsers" is to the code example above.

Comment: That looks like it should work, but it's also a little redundant. Your main logic can use the foreach(User user in db.Users) directly - no need to put them into a separate list.

Comment: Well i figured it would be better programming to first save all the users from each column in the database to a list, and THEN pull them out. But i suppose i could just as well pull them out directly and display them. But it would still give me the same error with either only pulling out the LAST added username or pulling out ALL the user names each time the foreach runs through itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the text of your question I understand that the content of allUsers is correct (i.e. 4 items), and that the foreach loop is executed many times.

Furthermore, your try with the boolean can't work since it will never enter the `isDoneAdding = true;` statement because the for loop is executed for i = 0 and i = 1, and will exit before i gets to the value 2. Even if that statement would be executed (for instance setting the condition as i == 1), the foreach would be executed two times and not only once.

To use the bool you should have done something like this:

```
bool isDoneAdding = false;

if (!isDoneAdding)
{
    foreach (var text in allUsers)
    {
         message += text.Bruger.ToString() + '\n';
    }
}
else
{
    isDoneAdding = true;
}
```

But If you say that the foreach is executed 4 times I don't think that this will work. I don't know the context of your issue, but suppose that your code is executed in response to an event and that this event is fired multiple times. Then you probably have the message variable which is defined outside the method containing the for loop (maybe an instance variable?) and get initialized only once. If this is the case you should define your isDoneAdding in the same place where message is defined.

Comment: Just tried your method, did not work. I still get the endless loop, it keeps adding the names again and again making a very fast scrolling text over the screen with all the names.